# Is there a "half secure" HTTPS that encrypts data but does not verify certificate?

Tags: encryption, https

As I understand, HTTPS has two major difference over HTTP:
(1) All transferred data are encrypted.
(2) The identity of the host is verified via a certificate.

Is there any similar thing to HTTPS that, it has the advantage of (1) but does not have the complexity of (2)?

I would assume such a thing is useful for a client-server application where the client knows the server is trustworthy, but wants to prevent data from being eavesdropped. However it does not seem to have been invented as per my research. If there isn't such a thing what's the reason behind it?

Comment: The certificate provides authentication of the server. This has nothing to do with proving the server is trustworthy, rather it proves the server you're communicating with is the one you intended to communicate with. Without authentication, you could be communicating with an attacker executing a person-in-the-middle attack (MiTM). There used to be unauthenticated TLS cipher suites in the form of anonymous diffie-hellman, but I'm not certain they are still available in modern versions of TLS. Some libraries allow you to ignore certificate errors, which is practically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I still have one question, that if I know the server address is "www.mysite.com" for instance, how is it possible that I am not communicating with the actual server? The DNS domain name needs to be purchased and one domain name can only go to one IP address right?

Comment: Firstly, the DNS protocol is (not necessarily) secure, so you can't trust the IP address you get back from DNS (unless you know a priori that your DNS is secure, e.g. DNS is using properly authenticated TLS). Secondly, you can't trust that your network packets are actually getting to the IP address you intend to send/receive from. The MiTM can change, reroute, and otherwise control all the data you send and receive.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for your patient explanation. I think I start to understand it now.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Will you put that in an answer, please, as I think it is worthwhile to provide an answer to this often heard question.